# Graphing random spikes with MapThread

Tags: plotting

I know that using `RandomVariate`, I can get this graph

`ListPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10],  Filling -> Axis]`

[image: ![enter image description here]

But I'd like to graph a function of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ and multiply it with random number above.
So I tried with `MapThread`

`MapThread[1/x, {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]}]`

which gave me a list of answers

> {(1/x)[19.9736], (1/x)[19.9392], (1/x)[19.9043], (1/x)[20.0796], (1/
> x)[19.9381], (1/x)[19.9299], (1/x)[20.0956], (1/x)[20.0913], (1/x)[
> 19.951], (1/x)[20.1328]}

But, I'm not getting any graph from

`Show[Plot[MapThread[{1/x},{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]}], {x, 0, 10}]]`

I must be missing something here.
I'm looking to graph a 1/x function but with random spikes.
Any suggestions? cheers!

Comment: Try `MapThread[#/x &, {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]}]` or 
`Map[#/x &, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]]` or , simply 
`RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]/x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = Transpose@  {Range[1, 10], 
   MapThread[
    Times, {Range[1, 10] /. x_ -> 1/x, 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 10^-1], 10]}]}

(*  {{1, 20.022}, {2, 9.96703}, {3, 6.69601}, {4, 4.97172}, {5, 
  4.02864}, {6, 3.33901}, {7, 2.84448}, {8, 2.49524}, {9, 
  2.22698}, {10, 2.01205}}  *)
```

then

```
ListPlot[lst, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Have fun!